# prevent downloading app images into device gallery?

Tags: android, download, android-gallery

How to prevent programatically downloading of app images into device gallery?

Customer doesn't want their artwork to be available in gallery.

Comment: May be choose their extensions? From .png or .jpg to any .zzzz?

Comment: you can save images in hidden folder in android ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place a .nomedia empty file in the folder, they won't show in the device gallery.

Comment: this looks promising. Thanks, I will try and come back with feedback

Comment: OK, works and I agree, my question is duplicate